# Xcode NSTimer error: Unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nstimer

I have a file called Util.swift with the following

```
class foo: NSObject {

    func sayHello() {
        print("hello")
    }
}

var globalTimer = NSTimer()

func startTheTimer() {
    globalTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: foo.self, selector: Selector("sayHello"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

When I call startTheTimer() in the viewDidLoad of any of my viewControllers, I get an error saying "unrecognized selector sent to class". I don't know what I have done wrong here.

Comment: As MudOnTire said, make it a class method. And also change the method signature to `sayHello(timer: NSTimer)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class func sayHello() {
    print("hello")
}
```

make this a class method please.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code here:

```
class foo: NSObject {

class func sayHello() {
    print("hello")
}
}

var globalTimer = NSTimer()
func startTheTimer() {
globalTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: foo.self, selector: Selector("sayHello"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Comment: You are calling the selector on the class itself not on its instances. SO using class function as a selector would work.